# SQL report data maniuplation

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a SRSS 2008 report that looks like following:

```
Amount | Total  
---------------
$11    | 5
$22    | 12
$30    | 8
```

This basically displays total number counts for each amount type ($11,$22 and $30).

The datasource where the report will be accessing has a table looks like following:

```
 Quantity | TotalPrice
---------------
  2       | $22 ($11 + $11)
  1       | $30 ($30)
  3       | $63 ($11 + $22 + $30)
```

So, the report should look something like:

```
    Amount | Total  
    ---------------
    $11    | 3
    $22    | 1
    $30    | 2
```

Is there a SQL trick that I can ahieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does the table with the prices have?  Is the TotalPrice column a string that shows what you wrote?

Comment: The TotalPrice has the summation of any combinations of each amount type ($11, $22, $30).

Comment: @tony - but does your `TotalPrice` contain the `($11 + $22 + $30)` bit also or is that implied?

Comment: @tony - also how do you know to use $11 twice instead of $22 once, and $11 + $22 instead of $11 + $11 + $11?

Comment: Oh sorry, no it doesnt contain the $11 + $22 + $30.  I was just showing how I came up with the total price.  So, just the totalPrice.

Comment: @Tony, you should provide a lot more info on the problem and possibly a schema of your table(s). I'm completely lost on how you know that $63 is $11 + $22 + $30 instead of $11 + $11 + $11 + $30

Comment: Where is your  detail table? If these are orders for instance you should have a table with all the line items listed separately Without one of those, the reporting you want is virtually impossible.

Comment: This looks like a special instance of the bounded knapsack problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition where not only does the weight (price) have to be exact but the number of items in the knapsack does too. NP-complete but for small items, like the three items mentioned, you could probably work it out in a reasonable enough time. As you increase the number of possible item/price combinations, the computation time increases exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Quantity | TotalPrice
---------------
  2       | $22 ($11 + $11)
  1       | $30 ($30)
  3       | $63 ($11 + $22 + $30)
```

I need to know a little bit more about the underlying/source data. Are you using sum and group by in the **TotalPrice** column calculation? And for example the first row from the above sample data you provided; are both 11 values stored on separate rows or is there one row that has the value of 22?